# 7zip command line synthax using wildcard

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008, 7zip

Based on this [source](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm), the following should work for the 7zip command line tool:

```
7zG a -tzip "C:\20131024_archive.zip" "C:\archive" *20131024*
```

The goal is to zip all the files containing the date in the name. However, this is not working for me as it zips all the files without the date filter.

I've tried all sorts of variants without success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the date filter goes into the target filename like so:

```
7zG a -tzip "C:\20131024_archive.zip" "C:\archive\*20131024*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `forfiles` if your using windows 7. Type `forfiles /?`  for more info. A think this will do what you want:

```
pushd C:\archive
forfiles /m "*20131024*" /c "7zG a -tzip C:\20131024_archive.zip @file"
```

I'm not sure this will work if the file name has spaces.

Comment: unfortunately I'm on windows server 2008